# Spring 2.x Properties outside of Jar file

Tags: spring-boot

- Spring 2.2.4
- jdk8
- Windows 10 running git Bash
- spring-boot-starter
- spring-boot-devtools
- spring-boot-actuator
- spring-boot-starter-web

I am trying to make properties (yml) properties available outside of the jar file.

Project:

```
~/Documents/NetbeansProjects/myApp/src/main/resources
application.yml
application-dev.yml
application-stage.yml

~/Documents/NetbeansProjects/myApp/target myApp.jar

~/Documents/NetbeansProjects/myApp/target/config/
application.yml
jdbc.yml
~/Documents/NetbeansProjects/myApp/target: 
java -jar myApp.jar --spring.config.name=application,jdbc --spring.config.location=file:~/Documents/NetbeansProjects/myApp/target/config/
```

All I get is the spring banner and termination of spring boot?????

Running from Netbeans or from git bash mvn using properties in the jar work.

Comment: "All I get is the spring banner and termination of spring boot". Please provide the exact output and as first try to diagnostic, increase the `org.springframework` log level to debug

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to acheive it:
**Programmatically**

```java
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("/Users/home/conf.properties"));
    properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(false);
    return properties;
}
```

**Environment Variables**

> export SPRING_CONFIG_NAME=application,jdbc
>   export SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=file:///Users/home/config
>   java -jar app.jar

**Command Line**

> java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=file:///Users/home/config/jdbc.properties

Hope it helps

Comment: Not interested in Programmatic or environment variable solution. I would use global solution over Environment: DevTools .config/spring-boot/sring-boot-devtools.yml which also didn't work along with --spring.config.name with and without spring-config.location even when moving the application-(env).yml out of src/main/resources